# Geonosis and Mustafar Apts

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I am just wondering if the above mentioned floors look similar in the Building screen and appear blank in the Album screen? I've attached a photo to make my query clearer.

[image]

Also, do you guys reckon, the developers will change their looks? :p

Comment: dat money 0.o I have like 50k.....

Comment: Keep playing, Kevin. ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, both these floors look different from each other in my Death Star. And my album shows these two floors as it should.

[image]
[image]  [image]  [image]

Comment: Thanks, Han for replying. Do you think there is anything I can do to make mine look proper? I think my Imperial Marches is looking like that too for now. Although it has design in the Album screen, it doesn't in the tiny black rectangle that is slowly showing its contents (imperial rewards at 1750). :(

Comment: Not sure if it would work but If you are playing on iOS (like I am), have you tried rebooting the app?

Comment: Yes, I am playing on iOS (iPhone 5s). Rebooting how? I have closed the app and then restarting my phone a couple of times since I read your answer. If that's what you meant. :)

Comment: Double-click on your iPhone home button real quick so that your most recent apps would appear in a list. Go to TDS and then flick it upwards. The next time you launch TDS again, you'll see that it's loading (and not just jump straight to Emperor Palpatine saying how much you earned while you're gone etc). Hope this helps.

Comment: Lol. That's what I meant by closing the app. Just tried it and failed again. :( By the way, I bet something else differs between your game and mine. Your 3 new limited edition characters, what do their silhouettes look like? Mine are nothing like droids.

Comment: Hmm... How should I say it? Like droids? The droids in your app are not the droids you are looking for?

Comment: I wanna show you photos to better explain what I meant but I can't add photos here?

Comment: Try saving the state of your TDS game via FB, then delete and re-install the app, and load back your TDS state. Could possibly work...

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. :(

Comment: My last suggestion is to email the devs or support. Hopefully, they'll be able to give you a solution.